# Passing string from IronPython to Javascript

Tags: javascript, python

I am new to Javascript and I have no idea how to get a simple string, which contains a path that changes, from my Pythonscript.

It is a local script so I dont have the possibility to write down a file and import it with Javascript or use a webserver to pass the data.

My Pythonscript sends commands to the Javascript. Both scripts work independent as long as I pass the path manually which is pretty annoying.

I am looking for something simple like in Bash and Python

Bash: 
`export myPath = 'myString'`

Python: 
`import os

myPath = os.environ['myPath']`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Encode the data as JSON and output it into a JavaScript section, e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var jsPath=<?python import json; print json.dumps(myPath) ?>
</script>
```

Except use the actual syntax for inline Python that your engine uses.